# Place function instructions successively in program memory

Tags: c

Say I have a program which controls some Christmas lights *(this isn't the actual application, only an example)*. These lights have a few different calculations to determine whether a light, `i`, will be lit in a given frame, `t`. Each of `i` and `t` is a `uint8_t`, so it can be assumed that there are 256 lights and `t` will loop each 256 frames. Some light patterns could be the following:

```
int flash(uint8_t t, uint8_t i) {
    return t&1;}

int alternate(uint8_t t, uint8_t i) {
    return i&1 == t&1;}

int loop(uint8_t t, uint8_t i) {
    return i == t;}
```

If I then wanted to implement a mode-changing system that would loop through these modes, I could use a function pointer array `int (*modes)(uint8_t, uint8_t)[3]`. But, since these are all such short functions, is there any way I could instead force the compiler to place the functions directly after one another in program memory, sort of like an inline array?

The idea would be that to access one of these functions wouldn't require evaluating the pointer, and you could instead tell the processor the correct function is at `modes + pitch*mode` where pitch is the spacing between functions (at least the length of the longest).

I ask more out of curiosity than requirement, because I doubt this would actually cause much of a speed improvement.

Comment: Use a select statement. It usually compiles to what you want.

Comment: Why do you need functions to implement basic operators like `&` and `==`? The `flash` doesn't even use the argument `i`.

Comment: @WeatherVane the scenario here is just an example, the actual functions are longer but of similar complexity between them.

Comment: You could do this by defining a control language, with instructions in an array. Those functions will almost certainly need access to the whole array of lights (for example to implement a "chase" pattern) but the question is far too broad.

Comment: @SamM check this out: it has examples in C (and other langs):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling

Comment: BTW, did you consider that the `modes + pitch*mode` method could be slower than `int (*modes)(uint8_t, uint8_t)[3]` approach?  A compiler could readily recognize/optimize standard code, yet non-portable code is trickier.

Comment: As for the performance implications, both solutions are going to include an indirect jump, which I would guess under all circumstances is going to outweigh the read of a pointer. The branch predictor will have similar chances of correctly predicting the jump in either case, and if the jump is correctly predicted, then the pointer read is going to be more or less free, whereas if it is incorrectly predicted, the mispredict penalty will outweigh it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not directly available in C. But such logic can be possible in assembler, and C compilers might utilize different assembler tricks depending on CPU, optimization level etc. Try to just make the logic small and compact, mark the different functions as static, and use an switch() block in C and look at the assembler the compiler generates.

Comment: As the answer says, there's no way to do this in standard C. There *may* be ways to accomplish it in compiler-specific fashions, like inserting top-level code alignment assembler snippets in GCC, but I think those would be quite fragile. Especially if compiling with optimization. It is, indeed, probably better to just write such code directly in Assembler instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch` statement, like:

```
#define FLASH     1
#define ALTERNATE 2
#define LOOP      3

int patternexecute(uint8_t t, uint8_t i, int pattern)
{
    switch (pattern) {
    case FLASH:     return t&1;
    case ALTERNATE: return i&1 == t&1;
    case LOOP:      return i == t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```